# What are the pros/cons of using a cferror tag vs. the onError method to handle errors?

Tags: coldfusion, error-handling

I would like to set up an error page which will diplay a message to the user, have the error logged, and have an automatic email sent out to the website administrator in the event of an error.
Which is better to use, a cferror tag or the onError method?

Comment: Not really an answer, but all my attempts to use cferror were broken of its restrictions and lack of flexibility. So if I can use Application.cfc and onError() -- I do this always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Application.cfm uses `<cferror>`, Application.cfc uses `onError()`.

Application.cfc is the preferred method for current version of CF because it can do things that Application.cfm cannot.  Therefore, one should use `onError()`.